# ScrollViewer Scrolling control for Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

I have to insert elements to a itemscontrol at top of the list. While inserting an element to the list at 0th position, list is scrolling to that item. But i don't want to scroll the item to the top of the list, when an element is inserted. Any ideas for making this possible.

Code of xaml :

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        <Button Height="72" Content="Add More" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" >
            <ItemsControl x:Name="MainItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding Item}" FontSize="28" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

My class Code:

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    private ObservableCollection<Model> mainList;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> MainList
    {
        get { return mainList; }
        set
        {
            mainList = value;
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainList = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        AddItems(15);
        ContentPanel.DataContext = MainList;  
    }       

    void AddItems(int numberIfItemsToAdd)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AddItems()");
        int start = MainList.Count;
        int end = start + numberIfItemsToAdd;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.Item="Item" + i;
           MainList.Insert(0, model);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddItems(1);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't been able to find solution for this problem myself, good luck with it :)